# Mock Principal for Spring Rest controller

Tags: java, spring

I have the following REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ExtendedGetUserDto getCurrentUser(Principal principal) {
    CustomUserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadByUsername(principal.getName())
    // .....
}
```

`CustomUserDetails` has a number of fields, including `username` and `password`

I want to mock principal in the controller method (or pass from test to the controller method). How should I do that ? I read many posts, but none of them actually answered this question.

**Edit 1**

```
@Test
public void testGetCurrentUser() throws Exception {

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
            USER_ENDPOINT_URL).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
    Assert.assertEquals("response status is wrong", 200, status);
}
```

Comment: You want to mock the "userDetailsService.loayByUserName" am I right?  Why not using when(userDetailsService.loadByUserName(principal)).thenReturn(cusomUserDetails); Or did I understand anything wrong in your question?

Comment: You should use a mocking framework for example mockito. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: 1. `CustomUserDetails` is injected in to the controller class.
2. I want to mock `Principal` not only for this test class, but other test classes, too.

Comment: Why is CustomUserDetails injected? You mean the userDeatilService is injected? As @Oleg said use for example Mockito to mock Principal. This would look like Principal p = mock(Principal.class)

Comment: Ok, let me add the test class maybe it makes my question clear.

Comment: As you can see, even if you mock Principal, the test doesn't pass it to the method. It's handled by the Security context and such.

Comment: As you can see, even if you mock Principal, the test doesn't pass it to the method. It's handled by the Security context and such.

Comment: Is `@WithMockUser` as explained [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-security-junit-test-with-withmockuser-and-withuserdetails-annotation-example-using-webappconfiguration) not an option? Note, the current user should be retrieved via the security context rather than invoking the user details service manually. This service should be invoked by Spring in the back and add the successfully authenticated user to the before mentioned Spring security context.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can mock a principal in your test case, set some expectations on it and then pass this mock down the mvc call using `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.principal()`.

I've updated your example:

```
@Test
public void testGetCurrentUser() throws Exception {
    Principal mockPrincipal = Mockito.mock(Principal.class);
    Mockito.when(mockPrincipal.getName()).thenReturn("me");

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .get(USER_ENDPOINT_URL)
        .principal(mockPrincipal)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
    int status = response.getStatus();
    Assert.assertEquals("response status is wrong", 200, status);
}
```

With this approach, your controller method will receive the mocked instance of `Principal`. I have verified this behaviour locally.

Comment: Although i have turned off security for testing, this approach works!